# Copying the contents of several directories in ant

Tags: ant

The following attempts to make copies of a list of directories. It doesn't copy anything. Are filelists not permitted to reference directories?

```
<macrodef name="collect-services-from-build-tree">
    <attribute name="src" default="NOT SET"/>
    <attribute name="target" default="NOT SET"/>
    <sequential>
        <property name="src" value="@{src}"/>
        <property name="target" value="@{target}"/>
        <filelist id="packages" dir="${src}">
           <!-- more like this -->
            <file name="interface/ui/ui-server/target/ui-install"/>
        </filelist>
        <delete dir="${target}" quiet="true"/>
        <mkdir dir="${target}"/>
        <copy todir="${target}">
            <filelist id="packages"/>
        </copy>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing :

```
        <copy todir="${target}">
            <filelist id="packages"/>
        </copy>
```

Into :

```
    <copy todir="${target}">
        <filelist refid="packages"/>
    </copy>
```